TypeError: ollama.chat is not a function in Node.js with the ollama module
I'm working on a Node.js project where I'm trying to use the ollama (ollama-js) module. However, when I call the async function chatWithLlama() (which has ollama.chat() inside), I encounter the following error:
TypeError: ollama.chat is not a function
And the chatWithLlama() function doesn't finish off.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
const ollama = require('ollama');

async function chatWithLlama() {
  try {
    const response = await ollama.chat({
      model: 'llama3',
      messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'Why is the sky blue?' }],
    });
    console.log(response.message.content);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
}

chatWithLlama();

For more context, this is my package.json:
{
  "name": "nodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@api/pplx": "file:.api/apis/pplx",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.6",
    "ollama": "^0.5.0"
  }
}


I have made sure that the ollama module is properly installed using npm and included in the package.json file and node_modules directory. I also have Ollama running on my Mac, with llama3 already installed. Nothing other than this error occurs, and the script does not crash. What's causing this issue and how can I resolve it?

Any reason you're not using ES6 module imports as per the documentation?

were you able to solve it? I had the same error and I just solved it. If you couldn't solve it, let me know and I'll write a detailed answer

In ECMAScript modules (ESM), this 2 basically represents the same thing:
import ollama from 'ollama';
import { default as ollama } from 'ollama';

However, when you write the same thing in CommonJS (CJS) (require() is a CJS only pattern), it is the equivalent of namespace import in ESM:
const ollama = require('ollama'); // CJS
import * as ollama from 'ollama'; // ESM

Therefore, in order to solve this issue, you should read it from an export named default instead. Here's a translation between default import in CJS and ESM:
import ollama from 'ollama'; // ESM
const { default: ollama } = require('ollama'); // CJS


The above answer is just a very simple overview on what happened. There's a lot of details about this and some additional reading that can be done include:

Reading from Node.js documentation: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/esm.html#esm_commonjs_namespaces
Understanding the use of __esModule: What's the purpose of `Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: !0 })`?

